# Radius of a circle.

Tags: circles

A hexagon is inscribed in a circle of radius $r$. Find $r$ if two sides of the hexagon are $7$ units long,while the other four sides are $20$ units long.

**Efforts made:** I've tried to construct  right triangles but i couldn't get anything usefull so far.

**Note:** This problem is meant to be solved by geometric methods.

Thanks in advance for every answer.

Answer (score 3):

Look at one half of the hexagon, and consider the angles subtended by the chords of length $20, 20$ and $7$.

We have $$4\arcsin\left(\frac{10}{r}\right)+2\arcsin\left(\frac{3.5}{r}\right)=\pi$$
Simplifying, this gives $$2\arcsin\left(\frac{10}{r}\right)=\arccos\left(\frac{3.5}{r}\right)$$

Now take the sine of both sides, together with a double angle formula and we get $$2\times\frac{10}{r}\sqrt{1-\frac{100}{r^2}}=\sqrt{1-\frac{3.5^2}{r^2}}$$

This is a quadratic equation in $r^2$ from which we can obtain the values $r=16, r=12.5$. I haven't checked if they're both valid, but can I leave that to you?

Comment: Could there be an even simpler approach  without involving trigonometric relations ?thanks btw for the answer

Answer (score 2):

Angle say $\alpha$ subtended by each of two sides having length 7 units at the center of the circle
$$=2\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\frac{7}{2}}{r}\right)=2\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{7}{2r}\right)$$
Similarly, angle say $\beta$ subtended by each of four sides having length 20 units at the center of the circle
$$=2\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\frac{20}{2}}{r}\right)=2\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{10}{r}\right)$$

Now, the total angle subtended by all six sides at the center of the circle is $2\pi$ hence, we have $$2\alpha+4\beta=2\pi$$ $$4\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{7}{2r}\right)+8\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{10}{r}\right)=2\pi$$
$$\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{7}{2r}\right)+2\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{10}{r}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$2\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{10}{r}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{7}{2r}\right)=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{7}{2r}\right)$$

$$\cos^{-1}\left(1-2\left(\frac{10}{r}\right)^2\right)=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{7}{2r}\right)$$ $$1-2\left(\frac{10}{r}\right)^2=\frac{7}{2r}$$
$$2r^2-7r-400=0$$
On solving above quadratic equation we get $r=\frac{7\pm\sqrt{(-7)^2-4(2)(-400)}}{2(2)}=\frac{7\pm{57}}{4}$
$$r=\frac{7+57}{4}=\color{}{16}$$
or $$r=\frac{7-57}{4}=-\frac{25}{2}<0$$ But radius $r>0$ Hence, we get $$\color{red}{r=16\ units}$$

Comment: is there a  solution which doesn't contains trigonometric relationships?